# Where stores AndroidStudio the VersionCode value in the .apk?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I'm making a project with AndroidStudio, but even after setting the VersionCode correctly in the gradle script, now it doesn't appear in the AndroidManifest.xml file.
 Is it stored in other file inside the apk?

More exactly:

1) I can't find any "android:versionCode" in my AndroidManifest.xml. To check the AndroidManifest.xml, I take the .apk, use apktool d to expand it to a folder, and then check the AndroidManifest.xml inside that folder

2) but, if I use aapt tool, this is the result I get:

```
aapt l -a my.apk | grep "android:version"
A: android:versionCode(0x0101021b)=(type 0x10)0x4e
```

Comment: in the AndroidManifest

Comment: versionCode and VersionName are mentioned in app-gradle file

Comment: I've edited the question to add more info.

Answer (score 0):

you can find **versionCode** and **versionName** in android studio only in app gradle file

Comment: Sorry, I mean where is it in the apk.

Answer (score 0):

Inside **Gradle scripts-->build.gradle(Module:app)** file.

```
android {
....
versionCode xx

versionName "xxxx"....

}
```

Answer (score 0):

now it doesn't appear in the AndroidManifest.xml file. ?

-- Yes. Your gradle will precedence over manifest version code, version name, application id(package_name) and others things.

Is it stored in other file inside the apk?

-- You can see everything in after application installed. (as application information).

Gradle will do building apk file with all flavors for you.

Answer (score 0):

> but even after setting the VersionCode correctly in the gradle script,
>   now it doesn't appear in the AndroidManifest.xml file. Is it stored in
>   other file inside the apk?

No it always stored into `AndroidManifest.xml`, as it always has been. You are looking at the wrong file tho. You should check for the one the AS generates for your through the manifest merger. You can find it here (for the debug flavor)

```
./app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
```

Comment: I'm checking the AndroidManifest.xml inside the generated .apk, and is not there.

Comment: it is there. What tool are you using to extract the manifest from the apk ?

Comment: I'm using apktool d myapkfile.apk

Comment: Then, I enter in the generated folder myapkfile and I open the AndroidManifest.xml file that is stored there

Comment: it could be a bug of apktook. Look [here](https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool/issues/782)

Comment: Thanks, you point me in the right direction. The thing is apktool don't extracts the versioncode, versionname and other parameters to the AndroidManifest.xml, but to other file called apktool.yml, placed in the same folder. That's why it's not appearing in the generated AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

The gradle file is not compiled into the APK, it is only for the actual android studio project for fetching dependencies. There is no way to get a gradle file from an APK

If you have written your versionCode and versionName in both your AppManifest.xml and build.gradle, the ones written in build.gradle will replace the ones in your AppManifest.xml when you compile your app, and here comes point

If you haven't written them in your AppManifest.xml, when you compile your app and build it, your versionCode and versionName written in your build.gradle will automatically be written in your AppManifest.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised no one has provided the answer to this (though it was eventually narrowed down in a comment). Firstly, the issue you were running into was one based on `apktool`. It appears that `apktool` does not put the `android:versionCode` attribute into the decoded `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Instead, you can find it in `apktool.yml` in the same directory.

Moving along, you may already be aware of the rest of this, but I'll include it for anyone else interested.

## More info:

Before going into even more depth, since you're already using `aapt`, you can use `aapt d[ump] badging file.{apk}` to get most of the info you're probably looking for, already converted into a readable form.

The output of `aapt l[ist] -a file.{zip,jar,apk}` you did is essentially giving you the output of `aapt d[ump] xmltree file.{apk} AndroidManifest.xml`; at least, that's where the section from which you're `grep`ping is coming.

### Resource value data types:

The `versionCode` value is actually already given in the dump output you provided. It's just not in decimal format. The `(type 0x10)` part indicates that the value following is an `int` type, and so you can just convert **0x4e** from hex to integer: **78**.

The only other "types" I've worked with from this xmltree (see above) output are `Raw`, i.e., when there's no type and it just gives a raw string; `(type 0x4)`, which represents a `float`; and `(type 0x12)`, which represents a `boolean`.

Occasionally for these other types, it will also have a `(Raw: "<value>")` section displayed on the same line, but, if not, you can convert the hex to a float value in a similar fashion. I know this question doesn't mention a particular scripting language, but for some examples, in PowerShell Core, you can use `[BitConverter]::Int32BitsToSingle($hexString)`, though behind the scenes it's first converting the hex string to an `Int32` as long as it's formatted correctly. In legacy PowerShell, you would need to do a bit more conversions, e.g., `[BitConverter]::ToSingle([BitConverter]::GetBytes($hexString), 0)`.

#### Examples:

- `(Raw)`:

  - Received data: `A: android:versionName(0x0101021c)="74.0"`
  - Value: `74.0`
- `(type 0x10)`:

  - Received data: `A: android:versionCode(0x0101021b)=(type 0x10)0xac09`
  - Converted value: `44041`
- `(type 0x4)`:

  - Received data: `A: platformBuildVersionCode=(type 0x4)0x40e00000`
  - Converted value: `7.0`
- `(type 0x12)`:

  - Received data: `A: android:value(0x01010024)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff`
  - Converted value: `true` (`0x0` would be `false`)

#### Additional resources:

You can find the enum declaring these types and others in [androidfw/ResourceTypes.h](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/2fedba9a32d9e92344eaf6e9faf5b43e1bc2ae70/libs/androidfw/include/androidfw/ResourceTypes.h) in the Android source. Currently, that's located at `android/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/libs/androidfw/include/androidfw/ResourceTypes.h`, but that's always subject to change, so the above link is to the current commit where it exists as of this post.

While I'm at it, the enum declaring these attribute resource constants (e.g., `0x0101021c` for `versionName`) can be found at [tools/aapt/Command.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/957168e2b2e90aae4c1846989e87d49fc4e7df3e/tools/aapt/Command.cpp), or the entire list for the platform can be found at [res/values/public.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/5ad6db77423479d027abb791ad3c02da39513a2c/core/res/res/values/public.xml). At present, those are `android/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/tools/aapt/Command.cpp` and `android/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/values/public.xml`, respectively.

Answer (score -1):

Inside app -> build.gradle file u will find versionCode

```
android {
       compileSdkVersion 23
       buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.consumer"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I mean where can it be found in the apk. I've edited the question, please check it again.